# Attempt to preg_match

Tags: php, regex

I've done this piece of code:

```
preg_match('/[\"\'><\/\\\]/', $foo))
```

The thing is, that I'm not really sure if that does only look up for following special chars or is there sth I missed?

```
< > " ' / \
```

The same case but for HTML inputs, is this right?

```
<input ... pattern="[^<>/\x5C;'\x22]+" />
```

Thanks for reply.

Comment: What is the problem with this?  What test cases have you used and which ones are not working?

Comment: you have an extra backslash fyi, this regex string should match each of the characters you're after: `/([\"\'><\/\\])/`

Comment: To make them identical (after the engine compiles it) I think it would be `preg_match('/["\'><\/\\\]/', $foo))` and `<input ... pattern="[\x22'></\x5C]" />`

Comment: @mikeb as I wrote, I'm not sure if this is right, it does what I expect it to do, but it's first time I do this so I'm not sure if it's right

Comment: @iam-decoder I tried as u wrote and that's not working

Comment: @tomik you're just trying to find all of those characters on the `$foo` string correct?

Comment: @sln thanks for correction

Comment: Why are you looking for these characters?

Comment: I order to die php validation, because JavaScript already announces wrong input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to test if these characters are present, [this should work](https://regex101.com/r/dP0gI7/1):

```
if (preg_match('/["\'><\/\\]/', $foo))) {
    ...
}
```

The corresponding HTML pattern to *disallow* these characters [would look like this](http://jsfiddle.net/ej5e0r5w/):

```
<input pattern="[^&quot;'></\\]*"/>
```

If you are trying to match these characters with the notion of making user input safe for insertion into a database or for HTML display, you are going about this the entirely wrong way. Check out `strip_tags()`, `filter_var()`, and prepared statements.